# Change that comes with につれて

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, jlpt

I encountered the following multiple-choice question on page 44 (question 1 in section 1) of my JLPT N2 grammar textbook 「新完全マスター文法　日本語能力試験Ｎ２」:

> 彼は（　　　）につれて、一人でいる時間が多くなっていった。
>
> ａ 高校を卒業する　　　ｂ 大人になる　　　ｃ 社会人になる

I chose 「ｃ 社会人になる」, but the answer given was 「ｂ 大人になる」.

My textbook explains ～につれて as

> #### ～につれて・～にしたがって
>
> 一方が変化するのと一緒に、もう一方も変化する。
>
> 前には、だんだん変化することを表す言葉（進む・上がる・多くなる<sub>など</sub>）が来る。「～につれて」は一方方向の変化の場合にだけ使う。[...]また、「～につれて」の後には自然に起こる変化を表す文が来て、意志的な行為を表す文は来ない。[...]

「ａ 高校を卒業する」 is not a continuous change (だんだん変化すること), so I eliminated it.  However, I cannot seem to identify a qualitative difference between options 「ｂ 大人になる」 and 「ｃ 社会人になる」:

> (b) 彼は大人になるにつれて、一人でいる時間が多くなっていった。
>
> He increasingly spent time alone as he became an adult.

> (c) （？）彼は社会人になるにつれて、一人でいる時間が多くなっていった。
>
> He increasingly spent time alone as he became a member of society.

It seems to me that both (b) and (c) are both unidirectional changes (一方方向の変化) that lie somewhere in the gray area between instantaneous changes and gradual transitions, but I cannot see a reason to prefer one over another.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

社会人になる is not a continuous change because it usually means （学校・大学などを卒業して）就職する・働き始める.

Comment: ... whereas 大人になる includes gradually acquiring "adult traits" and is not limited to reaching 成人年齢?  That makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @L.F. Right, 大人になる can mean 成長する "(gradually) grow up".